# Select max date per month

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table Inspection and I'm trying to select the max date per month per person. I want this in MS Access 2007 query and most answers i found is in T SQL format.

```
Date       PlateNo     TickeStatus
01-15-12       A        Open
01-23-12       c        Open
01-17-12       A        Close
02-23-12       c        Open
02-15-12       A        Open
03-23-12       c        Open
03-15-12       A        Close
03-28-12       c        Close
04-15-12       A        Open
04-23-12       c        Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Format` expression to create a calculated field, *month_start*, which is the first day of the month corresponding to the `Date` field value.  Then `GROUP BY` that *month_start* expression and `PlateNo`.

```sql
SELECT
    Format(i.Date,'yyyy-mm-01') AS month_start,
    i.PlateNo,
    Max(i.Date) AS MaxOfDate
FROM inspections AS i
GROUP BY
    Format(i.Date,'yyyy-mm-01'),
    i.PlateNo;
```

With your sample data stored in a table named *inspections*, that query returns this result set.

```sql
month_start PlateNo MaxOfDate
2012-01-01  A       1/17/2012
2012-01-01  c       1/23/2012
2012-02-01  A       2/15/2012
2012-02-01  c       2/23/2012
2012-03-01  A       3/15/2012
2012-03-01  c       3/28/2012
2012-04-01  A       4/15/2012
2012-04-01  c       4/23/2012
```

Comment: It works great. Thank you. Anyway how about if i want to pull out by date range. In my example, i want Between #1/1/2012# AND #3/30/2012#. The result i'm looking is like this: For Plate A: Date: 3-15-2012 TicketStatus: Close ; For Plate C: Date: 3-28-2012 TicketStatus:Close ..... Thanks again, really a great help

Comment: It seems you covered this in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501975/select-max-date-by-date-range