# Select Max Date by Date Range

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table Inspection and I'm trying to select the max date per date range I want. This is in MS Access 2007 query and most answers I found is in T SQL format.

For example Date Range: Between #1/1/2012# AND #3/30/2012#

```
Date       PlateNo     TickeStatus
01-15-12       A        Open
01-23-12       c        Open
01-17-12       A        Close
02-23-12       c        Open
02-15-12       A        Open
03-23-12       c        Open
03-15-12       A        Close
03-28-12       c        Close
04-15-12       A        Open
04-23-12       c        Close
```

In the date range I set. the result I want is like this:

```
Date       PlateNo     TickeStatus
03-15-12       A        Close
03-28-12       c        Close
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the maximum `Date` for each `PlateNo` within your target date range.

```sql
SELECT i.PlateNo, Max(i.Date) AS MaxOfDate
FROM inspections AS i
WHERE i.Date BETWEEN #2012-1-1# AND #2012-3-30#
GROUP BY i.PlateNo;
```

To get the corresponding `TickeStatus` values, use that as a subquery which you join to the inspections table.

```sql
SELECT i2.Date, i2.PlateNo, i2.TickeStatus
FROM
    inspections AS i2
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT i.PlateNo, Max(i.Date) AS MaxOfDate
            FROM inspections AS i
            WHERE i.Date BETWEEN #2012-1-1# AND #2012-3-30#
            GROUP BY i.PlateNo
        ) AS sub
    ON
            (i2.PlateNo = sub.PlateNo)
        AND (i2.Date = sub.MaxOfDate);
```

Comment: On the second SQL. You need to change every time the date range ---- WHERE i.Date BETWEEN #2012-1-1# AND #2012-3-30# ------ to get the result, I tried putting the date range in access query builder as criteria but different results. I was hoping the date range can be put as one of the criteria like my other queries where made a form to input the beginning and end dates. Thanks by the way for the reply. Appreciate it